# How to provide 100% width to li?

Tags: html, css

I have tried to provide 100% width to 'li' but its not working for me. Also i tried with 'px' but it will disturb above row. Please find  below css and html code and help me into this. Thanks in advance.

```css
.dndPlaceholder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr> 
        <td> Sample Text </td> 
        <td> Sample Text </td> 
    </tr>
    <li class="dndPlaceholder"></li>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That `li` should be inside a `ul` or `ol`, not by itself in a `tbody`.

Comment: But that 'li' added dynamically when we drag a row..

Comment: @ Federico klez Culloca td present under 'tr'.. i just provided sample code above.

Comment: Then there's something wrong with whatever you're using to implement drag and drop.

Comment: Wrap it in <ul>

Comment: @ Christoffer Hjärtström How to wrap it under <ul>/ <div> dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

`li` should be inside a `ul` or `ol`. Like as below example:

```css
.dndPlaceholder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="dndPlaceholder">Item 01</li>
<li class="dndPlaceholder">Item 02</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You are right but that 'li' part added dynamically from other template, so i cant update it. or if you have solution to put that li under div tag or ul tag dynamically pls suggest.